# Can I modify inbuilt Nginx variable with Lua?

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

the nginx log format is :

```
log_format  main  '$remote_addr [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" "$cookie_logintoken"';
```

I set the log_by_lua_file

```
log_by_lua_file xxxxx/ngx_lua_waf/log.lua;
```

and log.lua content:

```
ngx.req.set_header("User-Agent", "this is testing User-Agent")
ngx.req.set_header("Referer", "this is testing Referer")
```

and access.log change

```
127.0.0.1 [17/Dec/2016:16:21:47 +0800] "GET /test/client.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1370 "this is testing Referer" "this is testing User-Agent" "-" "-"
```

how can I change the nginx build-in var like $request ?   I want to change the 
"GET /test/client.php HTTP/1.1" before nginx log to access.log

ngx.var.request = "xxxx"  will be error :

```
failed to run log_by_lua*: xxxx/ngx_lua_waf/log.lua:15: variable "request" not changeable
```

but I dont konw how to change it with ngx.req.set_header

can anyone tell me how to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify several embedded Nginx variables using the Nginx Lua but the embedded request variable **`cannot`** be modified.

Actually, your starting assumption should be that embedded variables cannot, or, perhaps more accurately, should not, be modified.

Whenever you need a modified version of an embedded variable, define a custom variable, make your changes to that custom variable, and use this instead.

In your specific case:

```
    ### 
    ### Rewrite Phase ###
    ###

    #  Create your custom variable with a default value
    #  Runs before Log Phase so variable is available in Log Phase
    set $changed_request "-";


    ### 
    ### Log Phase ###
    ###

    ## log_by_lua* directives (Runs before inbuilt Log Phase directives)
    #  Update the custom variable etc
    log_by_lua_block {
        ngx.req.set_header("User-Agent", "this is testing User-Agent")
        ngx.req.set_header("Referer", "this is testing Referer")

        ngx.var.changed_request = ngx.var.request 
        -- Now do whatever changes you want to $changed_request.
    };

    ## Inbuilt Log Phase directives
    #  Define a custom log format with your custom variable
    log_format  customlogformat  '$remote_addr [$time_local] "$changed_request"'
        ' $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
        ' "$http_x_forwarded_for" "$cookie_logintoken"';

    #  Use your custom log format
    access_log /path/to/access.log customlogformat;
```

Comment: seems only way to do

Comment: it's worth to mention that `set` is not valid in `htt`p context, you should use it elsewhere (e.g location). As `log_by_lua_block` runs at nginx log phase, wherever you use set to define variable should work. nit: there is no `;` after log_by_lua_block.